# Scala: store call-by-name variable as class field

Tags: scala, dsl, callbyname

In my progress in Scala learning I try to implement a simple DSL with callbacks

```
object Button {...} // apply 
class Button(val name: String) {
    private val: => Unit; // doesn't work

    def click(f: => Unit) = {
        _click_cb = f
        this
    }

    def onClick() = this._click_cb()
}

Button("Click me!") click {println("Clicked!")}
```

I create a new object, pass it a callback to store. My demo framework fires `onClick` method, that should call the stored one

It works with `() => Unit` but my DSL looks ugly:

```
Button("Click me!") click (() => println("Clicked!"))
```

Sure, I could do `onClick` abstract and implement an anonymous class later

```
new Button("Click me!") {def onClick = println("Clicked!")}
```

But I want to play with some DSL and such

The questions are:

- How do I store `f` in `_click_cb`?
- How do I provide initial "empty" function for `_click_cb`?
- And maybe there's a more scala-way to achieve this? (without anonymous classes)

Comment: I'm guessing that `private val: => Unit` should actually be `private val _click_cb: => Unit` (_click_cb is missing).  But even so, it can't be val, right?  You are setting it in click(), so it would have to be var.

Comment: Also, the names click and onClick seem backwards: onClick should be the one you use to say what should happen when a click occurs, and click should be the one you use when a click occurs, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An uglier version just to show that lazy val can hold the by name parameter value without evaluating it:

```
case class Button(val name: String) {
  def clickCallback(): Unit = ()

  def click(f: => Unit) = {
    lazy val notEvaluated = f
    new Button(name) { override def clickCallback() = notEvaluated }
  }

  def onClick(): Unit = clickCallback()
}
```

A cleaner and more functional implementation:

```
class Button(val name: String) {
  def click(f: => Unit) = new Button(name) { override def onClick() = f }

  def onClick(): Unit = ()
}
```